# Is joining the British army permissible?

Tags: halal-haram, non-muslim, work

Asalaamu Alaykum,

As a Muslim, is it Permissible to Join the British Army even if your Intention and plan is not to become a soldier but to get a job in a different sector such as, Computing or Engineering?

Comment: This question has already been addressed in [Can Muslims fight in non-Muslim wars](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11300/can-muslims-fight-in-non-muslim-wars)

Answer (score 1):

As-salamou alaikoum dear brother,
I am far from being a mufti, but it's clear that the British Army or the French or the German do harm Muslims: think about Afghanistan, Iraq, Somalia, Mali, Syria.
Even working for the army of an "Islamic" country doesn't guarantee that you will not have to act against the Koranic laws: think about what the Saoudi army is doing in Yemen, or what the army in Egypt, in Algeria, in Morocco and others Islamic countries did, does and will do against the people.
Most if not all the armies of the Islamic countries do what the USA and its allies command: think again Afghanistan, Iraq, aso.
Even as a non Muslim I will never join any army: they all without exception harm people (Muslims or not).